# C# alternative to Tuple, perhaps using statics

Tags: c#, tuples

```
class A
{
    public int b;//gotten from the function
    public string c;
}

class B
{
    int func(int generator)
    {
        Values values = new Values();
        return values.b + generator;
    }
}


class Values
{
    int b;
    string c;
    string d;
    int i;

    Values()
    {
        b = 0;
        i = 0;
        c = "c";
        d = "d";
    }
}
```

We have a function to generate the int A.b, for example if we do B.func(1) and Values.b equals 1, then A.b will be 2.  However, the goal is to alter B.func to use B.func(int generator) to somehow populate A.c as well,
when we call B.func we have in the variable "values" the desired values for both A.b and A.c, but only A.b is returned.  So A.c IS contained somewhere in memory, and we want to populate string c.  The difficulty is 
that the return value of B.func is an int, not a string.  It seems like one way is to of ourse pass in both an int and string, so for example

```
class B
{
    Tuple<int, string> func(int generator, string c)
    {
        Values values = new Values();
        return new Tuple<int, string>(values.b + generator, values.d);
    }
}
```

But how else can we do this?

Comment: So you are basically asking how to return multiple values from a method? Whats wrong with returning a tuple? Why don't you like it? Can you use C#7 features? Tuples are easier to use in the latest language version.

Comment: I can use any features, I don't want to use a tuple, long story, although I might have no choice

Comment: C#7 `ValueTuple`s are a good solution, not sure what reasons are behind the long story... other than that you have the classic options: return directly an `A`, or pass it in as an argument to the method and modify it inside `func` accordingly.. or use `out` parameters for all needed return values.

Comment: how is valuetuple different from tuple?

Comment: `ValueTuple` is a value type, not a reference type. And c#7 has native tuple support which means that there is specific language syntax to make it easier to work with them. Read up on the subject, just google *new C#7 features*.

Comment: Simply giving the object to populate/complete as arg seems like a good approach here.

Answer (score 1):

C# 7 provides a few solutions to the problem.

Use a Value Tuple with [deconstruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct).

This requires an extra copy to allocate `ValueTuple(int, string)`.

```
class B {
    (int, string) func(int generator){
        Values values = new Values();
        return (values.b + generator, values.d);
    }
}

(a.b, a.c) = b.func(1);
```

Use an [out argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier#declaring-out-arguments).

```
class B {
    int func(int generator, out string c){
        Values values = new Values();
        c = values.d;
        return values.b + generator;
    }
}

a.b = b.func(1, out string c);
a.c = c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are working on something like hand-optimized obfuscation, I would recommend that you just return an A from your function because that's what the return value means and you already have the right field names for free as opposed to Tuple where the fields would have generic names.